# Does $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}=\sqrt[n]{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}}$ hold?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

Is it possible to do the following step? 
Are there any restrictions? 
I would like to know to not make stupid mistakes using Cauchy's criterion in convergence test.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}=\sqrt[n]{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}}$$

Comment: Not possible, since $n$ is limit-dependent.

Comment: It's not possible, because you can't take an $n$ outside of the limit if you are interested in the behaviour of an expression as $n\rightarrow\infty$. The way that the second expression is written, you'll just take the limit of the sequence $(a_n)$, but the $n$ on the root won't be involved in the limit process at all.

Comment: Consider $a_n=2^n$, for instance. The first limit is clearly $2$, while the second limit is... I don't even know what it means.

Comment: Related: [$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\vphantom{b}a_{n}}=\sqrt[k]{\lim_{n\to\infty}\vphantom{b^d}a_{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/761024/201168).

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. $n$ is bound to the limit, with your operation, you make it a free variable on the right side.

To be more concrete, a known limit is $\lim_n\sqrt[n]n=1$, which obviously can not work the way you are thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\sqrt[\large\color{#C00000}{n}]{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n}\tag{1}
$$
The index $\color{#C00000}{n}$ on the right is not bound by the limit. It is a free variable.

If $(1)$ is true and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists and is not $0$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1$ and thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n
&=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\right)^{\large\color{#C00000}{n}}\\
&=1\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
no matter what $\color{#C00000}{n}$ is.